# Use Ubuntu and Windows in the same Hard disk

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have Windows and Ubuntu installed on the same hard disk (I created two partitions). The problem is that I can get only to the last system I installed. I installed Ubuntu and then Windows and therefore I can get only to my Windows. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Of cause, install Windows on one partition (NTFS formated) and then install Ubuntu on your ext3/4 partition. During the ubuntu installation the installer askes you where to place the grub bootloader, install it on a partition and reboot your system. now the grub boot loader will ask you which operation system to start.

Comment: So how much partitions I need and what kind they should be?

Comment: 3, one NTFS for Windows,one ext3 or ext4 for Ubuntu and one Swap (which will be automatically created by the installer) for ubuntu swap

Comment: Another thing, If I have already installed ubuntu and then windows, is there a way to fix it? or i need to install ubuntu again?

Comment: well, i'm no windows user, but i think there should be a file named boot.ini, and you can configure the windows bootloader via Start->Execute "bootcfg /?" (this will show the possible options) and there you should also be able to activate a boot option for your already installed ubuntu. but im not sure.. maybe you try this and give a feedback.